# Improve for-loop through Cassandra's select ResultSet

Tags: python, pandas, cassandra, cython

In Cython, I'm trying to fetch about 600000 rows from a Cassandra table that has 10 columns. Then I will iterate through all of them. For the purpose of testing performance, here what I've done in `read.pyx`:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
import pandas as pd
import time

cpdef int get_max_volume():
    cluster = Cluster()
    session = cluster.connect()
    session.execute("USE trading")
    rows = session.execute("SELECT * FROM fx WHERE ins='EURUSD' limit 600000")
    max_vol = 0
    start = time.time()
    for i in rows:
        max_vol = max(max_vol, i.volume)
    print(max_vol)
    print(time.time() - start)
    return max_vol
```

Time taken of the for-loop is `9.449406862258911s`. This number is not very different from pure Python version.

I also tried to get the result by the form of Pandas DataFrame but it just gets worse. Many sources guide me how to improve for-loop, get `SELECT` result into DataFrame, and improve iterating through the DataFrame. But mixing them together makes the code take `~25s` to run.

Are there any other ways to improve this number? The query should be left unchanged.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why does the query need to remain unchanged? You need data from all 10 columns?

Comment: As I said, I'm just testing the for-loop performance, so here I just do a simple operation with one column. Later on, I may use other columns for analyzing. So don't mind the query. If you really need to know, it takes `~6 seconds` when I fetch one column.

Comment: Not Cython specific but I'd be tempted to minimize calls to max by calling it once with an iterable `max(i.volume for i in rows)`. Or better yet get the maximum with SQL maybe?

Comment: This doesn't look like the sort of code where you'll get much benefit from Cython though.

Comment: @DavidW That's the point right there. That's why I need optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase performance of going throw 600k rows - try to work with batches/bucketing, async calls, paging etc... - You have all the tools to run it in parallel and increase performance.

If you want to increase performance of this specific "loop", i'm not sure there's much to do - most of the time should be all the I/O part. You can overwrite row factory, use compression for transferring, work with CL_ONE.

Also, if you want to select "max", or other kinds of aggregates, you can try to move the logic to Cassandra and use UDF's/UDA's.